# My output is always driving Z value for pattern detector of 10110

Tags: verilog

The `pattern_det` is always driving Z.  The pattern to be detected is 10110 blocks of FSM will be like:

> reset-->S1(0)--->S2(1)--->S3(10)--->S4(101)--->S5(1011)-->S1(0)

At `S5`, if we get 0, then the transition will happen to S1 and `pattern_det` will get 1.

```
module patterndetector (clk,rst,data_in,pattern_det);
    parameter SRST = 3'b000;
    parameter S1 = 3'b001;
    parameter S2 = 3'b010;
    parameter S3 = 3'b011;
    parameter S4 = 3'b100;
    parameter S5 = 3'b101;
    input clk,rst,data_in;
    output reg pattern_det;
    reg [2:0]state,nxtstate;
    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst == 1)begin
            pattern_det = 0;
            state <= SRST;
                nxtstate <= SRST;
        end
        else begin
        
            case(state)
                SRST: begin
                    if(data_in == 0) begin
                        nxtstate <= S1;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                    else begin
                        nxtstate <= SRST;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                end
                S1:begin
                    if(data_in == 1) begin
                        nxtstate <= S2;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                    else begin
                            nxtstate <= S1;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                end
                S2:begin
                    if(data_in ==1) begin
                        nxtstate <= S2;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                    else begin
                            nxtstate <= S3;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                end
                S3:begin
                    if(data_in == 1) begin
                        nxtstate <= S4;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                    else begin
                            nxtstate <= S1;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                end
                S4:begin
                    if(data_in == 1) begin
                        nxtstate <= S5;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                    else begin
                        nxtstate <= S3;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
    
                end
                S5:begin
                    if(data_in == 0) begin
                        nxtstate <= S1;
                        pattern_det <= 1;
                    end
                    else begin
                    nxtstate <= S2;
                        pattern_det <= 0;
                    end
                end
                default : pattern_det <= 0;
            endcase
        end 
    end
    always@(nxtstate) begin
    state <= nxtstate;
    end
    
    endmodule


// TEST BENCH

`include "patterndetector.v"
module tb();
reg clk,rst,data_in;
wire pattern_det;
initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
end
initial begin
    rst = 1;
    repeat(2) @(posedge clk);
    rst = 0;
    repeat(500) begin
    @(posedge clk);
        data_in = $random;
    end 
    #10;
    $finish;
end
initial
begin
    $monitor("%t: clk = %b, rst = %b, data_in = %b, pattern_det = %b", $time,clk,rst,data_in,pattern_det);
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pattern_det` wire in the testbench is always `Z` because it is not driven by anything.

You need to add an instance of the design module (`patterndetector`) inside the testbench.  Simply compiling both modules and using `` `include `` is not sufficient.  For example:

```
module tb();
reg clk,rst,data_in;
wire pattern_det;

patterndetector dut (
    .clk          (clk),
    .data_in      (data_in),
    .rst          (rst),
    .pattern_det  (pattern_det)
);

initial
begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
end

// etc.
```

Partial output showing `pattern_det` as 0 and 1:

```
             120: clk = 0, rst = 0, data_in = 1, pattern_det = 0
             125: clk = 1, rst = 0, data_in = 0, pattern_det = 1
             130: clk = 0, rst = 0, data_in = 0, pattern_det = 1
             135: clk = 1, rst = 0, data_in = 1, pattern_det = 0
```